# Удаление слов в кавычках с учётом экранирования с++

Tags: c++, g++

Есть у меня проблема.Мне надо удалить в строке все слова внутри кавычек
(с учётом экранирования, т.е. если в строке я нахожу '\знак' то я пропускаю два знака - '\' и следующий после '\' ,а после проверяю дальше ) и вроде я это даже сделал ,но когда тестировал строку -

```
string test = " test \"\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\" hello world";
```

по какой-то причине она её неправильно вырезала и получилось - test \ hello world.

Код:

```
string main2 = " test \"\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\"  hello world";

string main;
long long nummerte = 0;
for(size_t x=0; main2[x];++x) {
    if (main2[x] == '\\') {
        ++x;
    }else if (main2[x] == '"') {
        nummerte+=1;
    }   

    if(nummerte%2 != 0) {
        x+=1;
        for(size_t y=x; main2[y];++y) {

            if (main2[y] == '\\') {
                ++y;
            }else if (main2[y] == '"') {
                x+=2;
                nummerte+=1;
                break;
            }   


            x++;

        }
    }

    main+=main2[x];
}

cout << main << endl;
```

Comment: во первых строка не может иметь такой вид, во вторых  не называйте обьекты именем функции  main

Comment: 1.В смысле не может если всё спокойно компилируется  и выводиться ? :) 2. Ну хорошо учту

Comment: есть ли регулярное выражение для этой задачи ?

Comment: Начнем с того, что `string test = " test "\\\\\\\\\\\\\"" hello world";` - не компилируется.

Comment: эмм а зачем ты строку изменил? я же в сообщении писал string test = " test \"\\\\\\\\\\\\\"\" hello world"; и в коде,а не  string test = " test "\\\\\\\\\\\\\"" hello world"; xD

Comment: Вы же текст вопроса только что поменяли, ну.

Comment: вы издеваетесь ? я ничего не изменял или вы очередной троль? Как же мне достал этот сайт одни тролли или идиоты которые смотрят на вопрос и вместо того что-бы помочь человеку они будут умничать ,но ответить на вопрос сами не могут лишь бы вставить свои 5 копеек.После этих слов меня забанять ,однако, stack пошёл на***

Answer (score -4):

Спасибо за ответы. 
Вот решение для тех, кто столкнётся с этой проблемой:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main ()
{
  std::string s;
  getline(std::cin,s);
  std::regex e ("\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"");  

  s = std::regex_replace (s,e,"");
  std::cout << s << std::endl;


  return 0;
}
```